# Shorter/cleaner code ternary statement

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator

Is there a shorter, cleaner way to write this?

```
<?php $a = ($a) ? $a : 'empty'; ?>
```

Comment: Not an optimization, but the parens are unnecessary; ternary operator has low precedence in C-like languages: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In php5.3

```
<?php $a = ($a) ?: 'empty'; ?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Be careful with this, if you're using isset: `$a = isset($a) ?: 'empty';` it will return a boolean... kinda of annoying as most of the time you don't get to use this feature.